# Google Maps Api v3 Firefox bug in Info Bubble

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-maps-api-3

I implemented the api 3 in wordpress with an external js and an action hook. It all works fine except in firefox, part of the info text does not display in the info box. See the screenshot [here](http://webspace.ship.edu/bwiens/gmapsff.png). It works fine in other browsers.

Here is my complete source code (or on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jtj5HAc4)):

```
var markers = [
    ['<a href="http://www.ship.edu">Shippensburg University</a>',
         40.06090, -77.52148],
    ['<a href="http://www.millersville.edu">Millersville University</a>',
         39.99680, -76.35440],
    ['Kutztown University', 40.50980, -75.78410],
];


function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.9, -77.5);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
            map: map,
             icon: '../university.png'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I used an array for the markers. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is please? You've shown us the broken case - what do you see differently in the correct case? Are there any errors in the Firefox script console? Is there anything else obviously wrong that might help debug this?

Comment: You are using the maps-API with visualRefresh , currently  different bugs related to infoWindows are open. I would suggest to use the old infoWindows instead(API-version 3.13, visualRefresh set to false) until V3.14 becomes the official release(with hopefully fixed bugs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an issue (or designed behavior, though why that would differ with Firefox is hard to explain) with the "experimental" [version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning).  If I set the "release" version

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3"></script>
```

It shows the complete text.